# Comparing two arrays in Mulesoft data view

Tags: json, mule, dataview

Need to compare two arrays and out put should be true or false

**Array 1:::**

Products
[

{
  Product:P1
  Customer:C1
},

{
  Product:P2
  Customer:C1
},

{
  Product:P3
  Customer:C1
},
{
  Product:P2
  Customer:C2
},
{
  Product:P1
  Customer:C2
},
]

**Array 2:**

Products
[
{
  Product:P1
},
{
  Product:P2

},
{
  Product:P3

},

]

Output should be true since Product P1,P2 and P3 combination exist against first array against C1

Please help me how we can achieve this in Data View ?

Comment: What is data view?

Comment: What is the MuleSoft product name? MuleSoft is the company name, not the name of a product.

Comment: my bad its any point studio data weave transformer mapping (1.0)(auto correction caused typo mistake sorry for confusion )